# Should I explain a bad grade that is not directly related to the program?

Tags: phd, application

I am applying for a M.S in Statistics in North America. I received a "C+" for my undergraduate topology course.

I am not sure whether I should explain that or not for two reasons. First, topology does not seem to be related to statistics anyway. Second, even if I explain that I was not feeling well, I have no evidence (since it takes forever to see the doctor here), so explaining it might actually make admission officers think I am lying. What should I do?

1. Explain even though I do not have proof from doctor
2. "Explain" but not mentioning the cold, just say something like "I will grow" (which I think it's technically lying?)
3. Say nothing

Comment: "topology does not seem to be related to statistics anyway" This is not true. Topology can be used to study geometric features of data.

Comment: Are you saying that where you did your undergrad, the final exam has that much effect on the final grade?  If so, yuck -- what a terrible system.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that there is little to gain by attempting to explain the C+ grade. If you are offered an interview for the position, or are otherwise invited to discuss your application, you could then ask the interviewer if they have any concerns over your grades. If they raise the topology grade, then you can explain then. If not, you've offered the opportunity.